# Red5 can't find JAVA_HOME

Tags: path, java, cygwin

I'm setting up a Red5 server on Cygwin

I get this

```
/usr/share/red5$ sh red5.sh
Running on  CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW64
Unable to locate Java. Please set JAVA_HOME environment variable.
```

However, I can also do this:
    `javac -version` and get `javac 1.7.0`, so I know that's installed, at least.

I can also go into the emacs `.bash_profile` and see that I've added this to the bottom:

```
export PS1='\w\$ '
export EMACS_HOME=~/emacs-22.3
export JAVA_HOME =/cydrive/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_32
export PATH=$PATH:$EMACS_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$EMACS_HOME/bin
```

So what's missing?

---

I edited `.bash_profile` to be this:

```
export PS1='\w\$ '
export EMACS_HOME=~/emacs-22.3
export JAVA_HOME=/cydrive/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_32/
export JAVA_HOME=$( cygpath -d "$JAVA_HOME" )
export PATH=$PATH:$EMACS_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$EMACS_HOME/bin
```

And I get this error

```
cygpath: cannot create short name of D:\cygwin\cydrive\c\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32\
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On mine it shows cygdrive. I think you are missing "g" on cygdrive:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_32/
```

[edit: added the g in cygdrive path still missing]

Comment: Yep. That was it. Now I just get a different error. related to some Java in Red5. Thanks